# How to merge cells using Google Sheets API with PHP?

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm newbie on this, I create a Google Sheets and put some content there using [PHP API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing_multiple_ranges):

```
$id_file = "XXXXXXXXxxxxXXXXXXXXxxx"; //ID sheet
$range = "A2:E2";
$values = [["INGLÉS","ESPAÑOL","DEFINICIÓN","FUENTE","COMENTARIOS"]];
$range1 = "A1:E1";
$values1 = [["GLOSARIO"]];

$data = [];
$data1 = [];

$data[] = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
    'range' => $range,
    'majorDimension' => 'ROWS',
    'values' => $values
]);

$requestBody = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesRequest([
    "valueInputOption" => "USER_ENTERED",
    "data" => $data

]);

$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->batchUpdate($id_file, $requestBody);

$data1[] = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange([
    'range' => $range1,
    'majorDimension' => 'ROWS',
    'values' => $values1
]);

$requestBody1 = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateValuesRequest([
    "valueInputOption" => "USER_ENTERED",
    "data" => $data1

]);

$response1 = $service->spreadsheets_values->batchUpdate($id_file, $requestBody1);
```

I obtain this result:

[image]

It works great but I would like to merge cells and some formatting on the first row, I would like a result like this:

[image]

Looking some information I tried with this:

```
$rangel = new Google_Service_Sheets_GridRange();
$rangel->setStartRowIndex(0);
$rangel->setEndRowIndex(1);
$rangel->setStartColumnIndex(0);
$rangel->setEndColumnIndex(5);
$rangel->setSheetId(0);

$request = new Google_Service_Sheets_MergeCellsRequest();
$request->setMergeType('MERGE_COLUMNS');
$request->setRange($range1);

$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
$batchUpdateRequest->setRequests($request);
$response = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($id_file,$batchUpdateRequest);
```

But it doesn't work, How can I fix it?

I'd like some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to merge the cells of "A1:E1" of Spreadsheet using Sheets API with php.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that your below script is almost correct. It is required to be modified a little. Please modify it as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
$rangel = new Google_Service_Sheets_GridRange();
$rangel->setStartRowIndex(0);
$rangel->setEndRowIndex(1);
$rangel->setStartColumnIndex(0);
$rangel->setEndColumnIndex(5);
$rangel->setSheetId(0);

$request = new Google_Service_Sheets_MergeCellsRequest();
$request->setMergeType('MERGE_ROWS'); // Modified
$request->setRange($rangel); // Modified

$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_Request(); // Added
$body->setMergeCells($request); // Added

$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
$batchUpdateRequest->setRequests($body); // Modified

$response = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($id_file,$batchUpdateRequest);
```

#### Additional sample script:

If you want to merge the cells and change the horizontal alignment to center like your image, how about the following sample script?

Sample script:

```
// Range
$rangel = new Google_Service_Sheets_GridRange();
$rangel->setStartRowIndex(0);
$rangel->setEndRowIndex(1);
$rangel->setStartColumnIndex(0);
$rangel->setEndColumnIndex(5);
$rangel->setSheetId(0);

// Merge rows of "A1:E1".
$request1 = new Google_Service_Sheets_MergeCellsRequest();
$request1->setMergeType('MERGE_ROWS');
$request1->setRange($rangel);
$body1 = new Google_Service_Sheets_Request();
$body1->setMergeCells($request1);

// Change horizontalAlignment to "CENTER".
$cellFormat = new Google_Service_Sheets_CellFormat();
$cellFormat->setHorizontalAlignment('CENTER');
$cellData = new Google_Service_Sheets_CellData();
$cellData->setUserEnteredFormat($cellFormat);
$rowData = new Google_Service_Sheets_RowData();
$rowData->setValues([$cellData]);
$rows[] = $rowData;
$request2 = new Google_Service_Sheets_UpdateCellsRequest();
$request2->setRows($rows);
$request2->setFields('userEnteredFormat.horizontalAlignment');
$request2->setRange($rangel);
$body2 = new Google_Service_Sheets_Request();
$body2->setUpdateCells($request2);

$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
$batchUpdateRequest->setRequests([$body1, $body2]);

$response = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($id_file, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

#### Note:

- This modified script and sample script suppose that Sheets API has already been able to be used.

#### References:

- [MergeCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#mergecellsrequest)
- [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)
- [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Yes! You were right! I applied your code and it works, but I also want to apply format like the image. I tried to use `Google_Service_Sheets_Color` for example: `$bgColor = new Google_Service_Sheets_Color();
    $bgColor->setRed(0);
    $bgColor->setGreen(0);
    $bgColor->setBlue(1);` and add the line `$cellFormat->setBackgroundColor($bgColor);`  but it doesn't work :/

Comment: @NekoLopez Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new issue, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, if you want to add ``$cellFormat->setBackgroundColor($bgColor);`` in my below script, please modify ``$request2->setFields('userEnteredFormat.horizontalAlignment');`` to ``$request2->setFields('userEnteredFormat.horizontalAlignment,userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor');`` and try to test again. If I misunderstood your situation, can you provide the whole script? I would like to confirm the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I applied that change and it works great!, I also tried to increase the font size of the title so I had to look for some information and  use `Google_Service_Sheets_TextFormat` according to this link: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Sheets_TextFormat.html  Domo arigato!

Comment: I have a question, If I want to apply format in the second row (A2:E2), just center text and bold, how can I define it?

Comment: @NekoLopez Thank you for replying. I'm glad your initial question and additional issue were resolved. About your new question, that is different from your initial question. So can you post it as new question? By posting it as new question, users including me can think of your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.